# NUnit use different objects as Test Cases

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I am trying to write an Update Test for different products (which are classes in this case) and different time steps :

```
public class UpdateTest 
{
    private static Product ProductLastYear;
    private static Product ProductTwoYearsAgo;
    public UpdateTest(Product product)
    {
        var previousReleasedProducts = new Products();
        ProductLastYear = previousReleasedProducts.GetProduct(Years.GetLastYear());
        ProductTwoYearsAgo = previousReleasedProducts.GetProduct(Years.GetTwoYearsAgo());
    }
```

Each product needs to be installed, and afterwards it is checked if the installation was successful (this is basically a pre-step before the Update). Right now, I am using two Tests for this:

```
[Test, Category("UpdateLastYear")), Order((int) NunitTestOrderEnum.Order.First)]
public void InstallPreviousReleasedProduct()
{
    using (var controller = new BootstrapperController(ProductLastYear))
    {
        controller.Install();
    }

    var successfulInstallation = InstallationValidator.ValidateInstall(ProductLastYear);
    Assert.That(successfulInstallation, Is.True);
}

[Test, Category("UpdateTwoYearsAgo"), Order((int) NunitTestOrderEnum.Order.First)]
public void InstallTwoYearsAgoProduct()
{
    using (var controller = new BootstrapperController(ProductTwoYearsAgo))
    {
        controller.Install();
    }

    var successfulInstallation = InstallationValidator.ValidateInstall(ProductTwoYearsAgo);
    Assert.That(successfulInstallation, Is.True);
}
```

Now, both tests have some code redundancy, which I would like to avoid. I was thinking about using TestCases for this, something like :

```
[TestCase(ProductLastYear), Category("UpdateLastYear"), Order((int) NunitTestOrderEnum.Order.First)]
[TestCase(ProductTwoYearsAgo), Category("UpdateTwoYearsAgo"), Order((int) NunitTestOrderEnum.Order.First)]
public void InstallPreProduct(Product product)
{
    using (var controller = new BootstrapperController(product))
    {
        controller.Install();
    }

    var successfulInstallation = InstallationValidator.ValidateInstall(product);
    Assert.That(successfulInstallation, Is.True);
}
```

Is something like this possible? I tried different Syntax for that approach, but it does not seem to work that easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use compile-time constants within attributes. However your `static` fields are no constants.

You can use the [`TestCaseSource`](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/testcasesource.html)-attribute:

```
[TestCaseSource(nameof(ProvideTestcases))]
public void InstallPreProduct(Product product)
{
    using (var controller = new BootstrapperController(product))
    {
        controller.Install();
    }

    var successfulInstallation = InstallationValidator.ValidateInstall(product);
    Assert.That(successfulInstallation, Is.True);
}
public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> ProvideTestcases()
{
    yield return new TestCaseData(ProductLastYear).SetCategory("UpdateLastYear");
    yield return new TestCaseData(ProductTwoYearsAgo).SetCategory("UpdateTwoYearsAgo");
}
```

However that assumes your static fields are already initialized, which isn't the case. So you need a static constructor for your testclass.

```
[TestFixture]
public UpdateTest
{
    public static ProductLastYear;
    public static ProductTwoYearsAgo;

    static 
    {
        ProductLastYear = ...;
        ProductTwoYearsAgo = ...;
    }
}
```

This is pretty much boilerplate for so little duplication. So it's a tradeoff if or of it not this is worth the afford.

Another opportunity is to introduce some static constant, like an enum that reflects the property to be used:

```
[TestCase(MyEnum.LastYear), Category("UpdateLastYear")]
[TestCase(MyEnum.TwoYearsAgo), Category("UpdateTwoYearsAgo")]
public void InstallPreProduct(MyEnum product)
{
    var Product = product == MyEnum.LastYear ? 
        ProductLastYear : 
        ProductTwoYearsAgo ;
    using (var controller = new BootstrapperController(product))
    {
        controller.Install();
    }

    var successfulInstallation = InstallationValidator.ValidateInstall(product);
    Assert.That(successfulInstallation, Is.True);
}
```

An enum is a constant expression, so you can easily use it within the test-attributes.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I wonder, is this considered good practice or is it better to write multiple tests (like I did before)

Comment: @kklaw This will probably be pretty opinion-based. From your current code it is purely fine to leave it as it is, as the source-attribute introduces some small complexity into the code. However if you have more such duplicates I'd refactor it the way I showed above.

Comment: I guess something is missing. First of all, I think you used the wrong type for the IEnumarable, I suppose it should be `public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> ProvideTestcases()`. Moreover, the product in the `InstallPreProductis` method is  specified as `null`, using your approach, resulting in an exception.

Comment: @kklaw I updated my answer with another opportunity.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I guess there is no "best" or most practical approach here. But it is useful to know how the alternatives (the ones that you introduced) work.